# Access SQL Query on same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables: one called EMP_Names which simply stores ID and Employee_Name and another table called EMP_Main which stores the main data and which refers to EMP_Names via IDs. Amongst other fields EMP_Main has fields called Technician_Name_ID and Leader_Name_ID which is related to EMP_Names. My problem is this: how can i run a query where both Technician_Name_ID and Leader_Name_ID resolve to Names? In other words both ID fields refer to the same EMP_Names.ID but I can only establish one relationship between the two tables.

Don't know if I'm clear because it's difficult to explain ...

Comment: Use the query design window and the query wizards if you are not used to SQL. It is a big advantage of Access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` but you need multiple joins.

```
select em.*, ent.name as technician, enl.name as leader
from (emp_main as em left join
      emp_names as ent
      on em.technician_name_id = ent.id
     ) left join
     emp_names as enl
     on em.leader_name_id = enl.id;
```

These are `left join`s in case the fields are not populated for all rows.